# Can somebody suggest me svg library for android?

Tags: android

Can somebody suggest me svg library for android? I have a list of objects with coordinates and I need to draw them like circles on a svg picture and on click a new activity shall be opened. It is importanrt that I can implement zoom in/out on that map.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a view and override the onDraw method which gives you the canvas.
Using the canvas you can draw circles.

Answer (score 0):

One svg library that works on mobile devices is [d3](http://d3js.org/). 
It can do everything you described. (Take a look at this [code example with zoomable circles](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535)).

[Here](http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/02/interactive-mobile-dashboard-d3-charts/) you can find a video tutorial that explains how to use d3 for mobile devices.